# Publishing app on google Crashes and ANRs

Tags: google-play-console

I am releasing my first game on Google, however I am getting an error on reviews by google team which does not make much sense for me. I wonder if someone can explain me what they want!

here is the details:
Error come under : Crashes and ANRs
Stack Trace : Native crash of App

```
  #00  pc 0x0000000000051994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000041814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::map(void*, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long, scudo::MapPlatformData*))
  #02  pc 0x0000000000041ec0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::reportError(char const*))
  #03  pc 0x0000000000042220  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::stringifyAction(scudo::AllocatorAction))
  #04  pc 0x0000000000043a20  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::deallocate(void*, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, unsigned long)+308)
  #05  pc 0x000000000001046c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so (eglDestroySyncKHR+228)
  #06  pc 0x000000000001cb5c  /system/lib64/libEGL.so (eglDestroySyncKHR+44)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000b88680  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #08  pc 0x0000000000b831bc  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #09  pc 0x0000000000b830c4  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000666df8  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #11  pc 0x0000000000666d8c  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #12  pc 0x00000000009644a8  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #13  pc 0x0000000000b3f71c  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #14  pc 0x0000000000b379a4  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #15  pc 0x0000000000b376ac  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #16  pc 0x000000000053202c  /data/app/~~s36mj0iluBigFDq4rUezfg==/com.CompanyName.GameName-RsdFbknBUtRayPyTuLnuRQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 959372996ed1ba1e)
  #17  pc 0x00000000000b63b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #18  pc 0x00000000000530b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

I tried to remove any code may cause the stop game like pause game on lose focus. But Google still sending me same crush report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that this is Unity's bug. So updating the unity engine to 2023 solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Begin by releasing the app on the `internal testing` track, and then examine the `pre-launch reports`. These reports contain crash logs, screenshots, and crash video recordings, which are very useful.